# While printing a CMYK file to Adobe Pdf, the CMYK values change

Tags: color, pdf, print-design, color-conversion

I have created an application that produces CMYK documents. They print well in "Microsoft Xps document writer" and are still in CMYK and carry the exact color values I've designed in my application.
When I repeat the printing into Adobe Pdf, the CMYK values change. This is unwanted behavior, I want my exact color values retained. I've tried setting the "color management policies" to "leave color unchanged" with no success.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please explain "print to PDF" what OS are you on? How do you check the CMYK values of the PDF?

Comment: Windows 8, I check CMYK values using Adobe illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the following is a solution to this problem:

1. edit adobe pdf printer color settings to "do not change colors"
   and then save these settings to a .joboptions file.
2. Go to acrobat settings, in "Convert to Pdf" select "Xps" and then
   click "edit settings".
3. Select the settings you've saved in step 1.
4. 4-Print your Wpf content to "Microsoft Xps document writer" to get
   an Xps file
5. open the Xps file directly in acrobat and save it as pdf

Done!

You can use acrobat sdk which is freely available from adobe website, to automate this process (unfortunately acrobat has vary limited command prompt options, so using the sdk seems to be the only option)

Comment: Cool. How can the graphic design group members take advantage of the procedure you outline here?

Comment: Aside from the initial configurations, the procedure can be automated in our application, I've already tested automating the conversion using acrobat sdk. The only question is if we can set the xps printing process to not show the save dialogue and save the file to a programmaticaly determined location? My experience from the past week says this should be a simple problem with an unnecessarily difficult solution. Let me do some test, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft XPS has a different colour engine from Adobe PDF. It is unlikely that a document produced in one will play nice with the other. The XPS is non-standard. Adobe PDF X/1a has become the de facto standard for Press-ready PDF formats.

Edit: Here are your options:

- Accept the difference in colour due to using your software
  combination.
- Stick with XPS (using Microsoft Xps document writer) to preserve your
  design integrity.
- Redo the artwork to avoid the inherent problem in different colour
  rendering.
- Locate a suitable **XPF to PDF Converter** to ease one into the other. There are several that come up with a search.

Good luck.

Comment: for the fourth option, can you point me to a few samples?

Comment: Also, we  don't care about color reproduction accuracy. Other factors are important, and when we ask for c:0,m:1,y:0,k:0 we mean it, no matter what the exact color will look like.
Some options in the adobe pdf printer seem to address this problem, but it seems to me that anything we print to it is first converted to RGB, and then processed.
I know that old printer drivers in windows were limited to RGB, but no information about most recent versions of Adobe acrobat and new versions of windows. As for the output, it still messes the colors.

Comment: @Alireza Search the web using the wording that I set in bold face. You'll get at least ten different utilities that claim to do what you wish.

Comment: @Alireza Your comment about not caring about color reproduction accuracy along with your necessity for retaining colour values is baffling. Values generated in one application for one purpose is of little use in a different application, AFAIK.

Comment: Of course I've already tested some of these tools. All of those tested are problematic, either in handling CMYK colors or in handling complex scripts (mixes of RTL and LTR scripts) (most of them had both problems!).

Comment: No it is not. I have messages, that are designed in single ink colors, like pure shades of magenta somewhere and pure shades of black somewhere else. Nowhere in the design, the two colors are mixed. This is a requirement by the customer and I've reflected it in the software design. After some workflow, the end result is created and they want it to still keep the "single-ink everywhere" feature, which is lost while converting to Pdf.

Comment: @Alireza It is understandable that the fourth option is problematic due to the answer I gave. You cannot turn lead into gold. Microsoft came up with a proprietary process to circumvent convenient work with competitors. They're known for avoiding standards established by others in favour of their own brands. They run a closed shop. So does Adobe; but, Postscript and PDF has been given away to the public domaine. XPS remains proprietary. Now, come up with a utility that works between the two seamlessly and you've got a product. Good luck.

Comment: You are, unfortunately, totally right. The point is that Xps is not a singular technology, it is tightly integrated with wpf, which is great for creating dynamic graphics easily. During this time I had to work around this limitation, I knew about many artificial limitations imposed to this area of computing: printing. I might someday write a complete blog post about this, and how this means bad experience for Microsoft technology adopters.
Thanks.